# Calling a Python app from Java

Tags: java, process, command, jython

I am unfamiliar of the way how to use Jython to call a Python app from my Java (Spring Boot) Application, so **I usually use the following method to retrieve the json response from the python app:** (the Java app is running on a CentOS7 environment)

```
   StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

   Process p;
   try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.debug(line + "\n");
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
```

**That is helpful when I call any python application, which gives me back nothing but a single line**, like *{"status":"ok"}*

But if it gives me back multiple lines, or an exception after giving me back the json answer I expect, my Java application returns an empty string, like if it wouldn't get any response back from the Python app.

Though when I run the same command via terminal, I get the multiple line answers.

So I wonder if the issue is with my code? Am I missing something to see here which obstructs me to have multiple lines from the answer? I need the answer regardless of how many lines I get back.

Answer (score 0):

Your methode has nothing to do with Jython or Python in general. You are just starting a new Process and reading its standard output.
It just happens that in your case this is a python app and the output should be json (but could be anything).

If I understand you correctly, you only want to "accept" one line json outputs from your python process. Try this:

```
public String getOutputFromProcess() {
   //Use StringBuilder instead of Buffer if you dont need the thread safety
   StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
   StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

   //Removed error handling for simplicity
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py");
   p.waitFor();   //Maybe this needs to be moved after the reading part
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

   //You also need to read the standard error output
   BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    String line = "";
    int counter = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
        counter++;
    }

    while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
       error.append(line + "\n");
    }

    //Check if we have read more than one line
    //If yes return empty string or null etc.
    if(counter > 1) return "";

    //Here you should check if this is a valid json string
    return output.toString();
}
```

In general I would suggest you have a look at Jython and call the python function directly. If you want to use your methode, have a look at `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you for your response HectorLector. I didn't say this has anything to do with Jython. I said I am unfamiliar with that concept, but I solved this issue in another way. I removed the counter from this solution as the whole point is for me to get the answer even if it contains multiple lines. Using your solution I get the same issue as I get with my version. A single-line response appear in the output of this, but if the Python App returns multiple lines, the code doesn't pick them up, it will only return with an empty String.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure your python app finished execution? (Maybe its stuck or there is an endless loop).

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the solution in my case was to create a shell script serving as a bridge between the Java and the Python app. 
  For some reason this python app I want to use simply doesn't return with any answer when there would be multiple lines.

There are several workaround on this, probably the best to go with is Jython, as @HectorLector advised.

Also it works when I create a shell script which calls the Python app, and my Java app calls the shell script instead of the Python file.

Another solution is to run the command with an additional *> output.txt* 
 in the command, which will make sure that the called process' output will flow into the specified file. Then later the application can retrieve the data from that file, and delete it when it is not necessary anymore.